# howto access ubuntu one CouchDB

Tags: ubuntu-one, development, couchdb

I'm trying to connect to the cloud CouchDB at ubuntu one, but i always get the following error message:

> {"error":"unknown_error","reason":"function_clause"}

I tried following requests:

> https://couchdb.one.ubuntu.com/u%2F8e4%2F437%2F554355%2Fcontacts/_all_docs
>   https://couchdb.one.ubuntu.com/u%2F8e4%2F437%2F554355%2Fcontacts%2F_all_docs
>   https://couchdb.one.ubuntu.com/u%2F8e4%2F437%2F554355%2Fcontacts/_all_docs

The same error occurs if i try to get the welcome string from the db.

Does anyone has an idea whats going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Therese was a problem with the OAuth header. It was malformed. It worked on other Ubuntu one pages this was confusing me. This site helped me: http://hueniverse.com/2008/10/beginners-guide-to-oauth-part-iv-signing-requests/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a authentication

https://username:password@couchdb.one.ubuntu.com/xxxxxxxxx

Comment: I signed my Request with OAuth.
An HTTP authorization isn't required.